# Manually added Link missing in Mobile menu

Tags: php, wordpress, add-filter

I added a link to my WordPress menu using the “wp_nav_menu_items” hook. It works perfectly well in the normal widescreen menu but it does not show up in the mobile dropdown select menu. Is there a different hook that I need?

Here is my code (in my themes Functions.php file):

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

    $url = ThemexUser::$data['user']['profile_url'];
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'main_menu' ) {
        $items .= '<li class="menu-item"><a href="'.$url.'">My Profile</a></li>';
    }
    return $items;

}
```

Some visuals, just to be clear:
[Normal Menu (Added link appears)](https://postimg.org/image/6kklpei5h)
[Mobile Menu (Added link is missing)](https://postimg.org/image/hivv7l6qt)

I want the “My Profile” link to show in the mobile menu as well. The theme in use is LoveStory By Themex (Version 1.15) which has been completely redesigned by a custom child theme.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: i am not familiar with wordpress, but i would suggest you examine other links in menu (both normal and mobile) and check if there is not missing some css class or id for js

Comment: I added the same classes and structure of the rest of the menu items but it did not make a difference